# sql query to list all rows if column date with current date exceeds 24 hrs

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks in advance,I am using Mysql database. Actually i need a row of data whose order_date column with datetime datatype exceeds 24 hrs when comparing with current date and time. Other table with name "checks" contains same orderid compared with carts table orderid. 
so i need a sql query to get a row of carts table data when comparing carts order_date with current date and carts table with orderid same as checks table orderid should be neglected.

```
carts table:
S.No | username | orderid             | exam_name | order_date         |
1    | Rakesh   |746G797W819d3343493z | PMP       | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |
2    | Rakesh   |746G797W819d3343493z | CAPM      | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |
3    | Kulkarni |24890W819d6743493W   | CAPM      | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |
4    | Suresh   |52890W819d6743493W   | PMP       | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |
5    | Gautham  |90890W819d6743493W   | PMP       | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |

checks table:
S.No | username | orderid             | exam_name | checked_date         
1    | Rakesh   |746G797W819d3343493z | PMP       | 2016-11-07 11:20:5   
2    | Kulkarni |24890W819d6743493W   | CAPM      | 2016-11-07 11:20:5
```

Remaining rows as below is needed

```
S.No | username | orderid             | exam_name | order_date         |
1    | Rakesh   |746G797W819d3343493z | CAPM      | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |
2    | Suresh   |52890W819d6743493W   | PMP       | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |
3    | Gautham  |90890W819d6743493W   | PMP       | 2016-11-05 11:34:5 |
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using! (When it comes to date/time too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.) Column data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    carts
LEFT JOIN
    checks ON
    carts.orderid = checks.orderid AND
    carts.exam_name = checks.exam_name
WHERE 
    checks.orderid is null AND
    checks.exam_name is null AND
    carts.order_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: I am getting error as below #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN
    checks
    ON carts.orderid = checks.order_id
WHERE
    checks.o' at line 5

Comment: Apologies @RagithThomas I should have been using OUTER JOIN not FULL OUTER JOIN. 
Just to check, your pasted comment uses checks.order_id but in the checks table above the column name is ordered, which one is correct ?

Comment: @RagithThomas Change `OUTER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. In my database checks table column name is order_id so no problem i changed as per table column but i am getting the error as #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN
    checks
    ON carts.orderid = checks.orderid
WHERE
    checks.or' at line 5

Comment: Word "OUTER" in MySQL not needed. It  optional additive for "LEFT/RIGHT"

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks @Mike ! Have edited accordingly. Haven't used MySql in a while...

Comment: Writing the sql query SELECT
    *
FROM
    carts
LEFT JOIN
    checks
    ON carts.orderid = checks.orderid
WHERE 
    checks.orderid is null AND
    carts.order_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY       is working fine . I have included the second row with same name Rakesh as third row name.Using the query is removing all data of Rakesh. The courseid and orderid should be compared and removed. Please go through the edited above things

Comment: @RagithThomas I've added the extra check for carts.exam_name = checks.exam_name

Comment: Instead of removing the row of checks which is present in the carts table, comparing the orderid and exam_name of both the table should be removed

Comment: Thank you very much Greg Lever query is working fine

Comment: Great ! Glad to hear it @RagithThomas :)

Comment: How to get rows for a particular ids

Comment: @RagithThomas in the WHERE clause just add order_id = some_order_id

Comment: Actually i am passing userid from the function so only for the particular userid the above query should execute

Comment: How are you passing the userid into the query within your function @RagithThomas ? Perhaps you could use some form of string formatting ?